# in java,how to stop the tailer thread if input file is not found

Tags: java, taillistener

i am using java `tail-listener` api to do monitor the log messages from the given input log file.Here my code is given below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
{
 files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
 File pcounter_log = new File(files);                                
 Tailer logMessages = new Tailer(pcounter_log, new FileListener(files,element.getLogPattern()),
                                        5000, true);
 Thread thread = new Thread(logMessages);  
     thread.start();

}

public class FileListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

 private final String fileName;

 public FileListener(String fileName, ArrayList<String> pattern) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
 }
  public void handle(String line) {

    System.out.println(fileName+"<---->"+line); 
    }
}
```

in above code,if any of the file is not found in the middle of execution,how to stop the corresponding tailer.

how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`File.exists()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

```
 if(pcounter_log.exists()) {
        Tailer logMessages = new Tailer(pcounter_log, new FileListener(files,element.getLogPattern()),
                                        5000, true);
        Thread thread = new Thread(logMessages);  
        thread.start();
 }
```

Comment: if file is deleted in the middle of execution,how to handle this

Comment: @WithIssue: if you are running it in window OS, OS won't let you delete it whereas in the case of *nix, the inode is still available.so you can continue to read.

Comment: @John : i am running this in linux.in linux,we can do force delete.

Comment: @WithIssue: yes. that is what i said. but you can still read it.

Comment: @John : ok ..got it ..but it is unnecessary execution right.how to avoid this . r u working with this api. if yes,i have more doubts on this ..

Comment: @WithIssue: sorry. i don't have experience with this api.

Comment: @WithIssue How about running another thread which loops around these files continuously and then performs thread.stop() if it doesnt find the corresponding file?

Answer (score 0):

> ... if any of the file is not found in the middle of execution,how to stop the corresponding tailer.

The fundamental problem is that a file is "found" when you try to open it.  Once it has been opened, the Java application doesn't need to find it again:

- On Windows, OS-level file locking means that the file typically cannot be deleted (e.g. by another application) until your application closes it.
- On UNIX / Linux, a file *can* be deleted (actually "unlinked") while it is open, but this does not affect an application that currently has the file open.  The application can continue to read and write the unlinked file ... even though no other application can open it.

With Java 6, the only way to tell if the file you are currently reading / writing has been "deleted" is to attempt to open it again.  That is expensive if you are doing it repeatedly.  In Java 7, there are new classes for processing file system events that would allow your application to "notice" that a file has been deleted / unlinked.